# Has anybody using core-plot seen the following error "'CPTAnimation.h' file not found"

Tags: xcode, core-plot

Trying to create the minimal core-plot project - http://www.mobdevel.com/?p=96

I've installed core-plot as a static library.

When I try to run the program I get the following error

CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h:4:9: 'CPTAnimation.h' file not found

When I move it "up" I get the error with the next file "below" 'CPTAnimationOperation.h' file not found

header search path is correct I believe ../core-plot/framework

( source is just beneath it)

I'm sure it's something dumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

needed to be ../core-plot-master/framework/Source

Had originally stopped at framework because adding  /Source  gave error of CPTPlatformSpecificDefines.h not found

so I had to add additional search path of ../core-plot-master/framework/iPhoneOnly as well

Answer (score 1):

There is an other solution is to add the header search path **/core-plot-master/framework** then select **recursive**, this worked for me.